# Connect API called via WebIntent: Unsupported API

Tags: cordova, ionic3, square-connect

I am stumped and hoping for a little help! I need to fire up square to launch a transaction, I have an Android app I wrote with Ionic/Cordova, it has a plugin to fire intents either via sendBroadcast, startactivity or startactivity, these map directly to native android functions.

I am preparing the bundle for extras and adding this pair:

```
'com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION': "2.0",
```

I do get the activity to start and square appears but it reads,

> The installed version of Square Point of Sale is too old. it doesn't support this version of the SDK.

Has anybody run into this for and does anybody have a potential solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating your version of Square Point of Sale from the google play store? Based on the error, that should be the solution. What version are you running?

Comment: I am running the latest from the play store, it almost seems like sending the bundle is not recognized.  I am firing this from a cordova app -- using the webintents plugin.  It works with all other uses but seems to have an issue with square, it's quite curious.